# How to do insert (figure) caption in microsoft word so it can go from Fig 1.1, 1.2, to 3.1, 3.2?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te8bw_6lar0) and other instruction to learn about how to tag the figure titles in a Word document, for the purpose of making a table of figures at the end. I can do it if all the figures are in chronological order: Figure 1, followed by Figure 2, followed by Figure 3...

But I need to do both of the followings:
1) Enable subsection such as Figure 1.1 followed by Figure 1.2.
And 2) Allow skipping in front number such as Figure 1.1, followed by figure 1.2, then followed by Figure 3.1, and then Figure 3.2.

I have been messing around with the "Insert Caption" settings with no success.

Comment: The type of caption numbering that you want assumes that the headings for your subsections are actually numbered (that is, that you've set up a multilevel list for them). Are they?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this seems to do the trick - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-chapter-numbers-to-captions-in-Word-76aa8706-3453-4a72-ad5c-b87d90ce1698